# I need a format of xtype datefield full of month eg: march september in AEM

Tags: aem, xtype

I am using a datefield xtype in my AEM and I need a output in the form of ( 23 September 2022) but I don't know the format.I am using the format (d M Y),now I am getting 23 Sep 2022).but I need the month fullform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the format for your requirement will be `d F Y`.

From [ExtJS reference docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.Date.html),

```
 F - A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
 M - A short textual representation of a month, such as Jan or Mar
```